# PHPMailer return to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

Currently I' am setting up a email verification system for my personal site. I (try) to handle this with jQuery and AJAX (code follows). But the problem is that it does not return to the echo 2; in my signup.inc.php so that I can continue working in the AJAX call.

As I understand it the compiler should return to/continue from the point where it was redirected, in this case the `send_ver_email($user_email)` below and echo 2. What did I get wrong? This is pretty new to me and I don't have so much experience , but I don't not what else to try. Tried moving and merging documents, but nothing works.

The AJAX call in JS:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'include/signup.inc.php',
                    data: 'user_name=' + user_name +
                    '&user_email=' + user_email +
                    '&user_pw=' + user_pw,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data == 0) { // invalid email
                            ... do something

                        } else if (data == 1) { // account already exists
                           ... do something

                        } else if (data == 2) {

**This is where it should land after the successful sign up**                         

                            return false;

                        }

                    }

                });
```

signup.inc.php works great and stores the data in database, so this is not the problem:

```
include_once "dbc.inc.php";
include_once "verification.inc.php";

if (isset($_POST)) {

    //get posted data;

    //select $statement

    // error handlers

    if (filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        echo 0;
        exit();

    } else if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 1;
        exit();

    } else {
        // db entry (works great no problems there)


        send_ver_email($user_email);

        echo 2;
        exit();

    }

}
```

the AJAX receives the 2 and reacts as intended if `send_ver_email($user_email)` is disabled, so I'am very sure that it has something to do with the structure or the way send() handles things. This function is included in verification.inc.php which includes the whole PHPMailer package. And the Email works too! I get every single mail

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

include_once "../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
include_once "../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
include_once "../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";

function generate_ver_code() {

    // ...

}

function send_ver_email ($user_mail) {

$verCode = generate_ver_code();

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '.......';
$mail->Password = '........';
$mail->setFrom('........', '.......');
$mail->addAddress('.........', '..........');
$mail->Subject = '...........';
$mail->Body = "......................";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->AltBody = '.........';

$mail->send()
```

}

I am also very grateful for tips about code style and layout :)

EDIT 1: A different approach:

```
if($mail->send()) {
        echo 2;
        exit();

    } else {
        // some error handling

    }
```

This does not crash, I logged everywhere around it, but the ajax still does not register the echo 2

And another try showed:

```
if($mail->send()) {

        } else {
            // some error handling

        }
```

and in signup.inc.php:

```
   send_ver_email($user_email);
    --------LOGGED HERE---------
    echo 2;
    exit();

}
```

This works fine too... this weirds me out the most. Either I got a really dumb typo somewhere or another newbie mistake (hopefully) or ajax handles this echo calls in a very confusing way.

Comment: please show complete `send_ver_email` then. Or check if there is any `exit;`, `die()` in there.

Comment: Code edited. Neither exist that's why I have no clue what to do

Comment: does it crash before that echo statement? Have you got PHP error reporting turned on? In that instance, does your ajax call return successfully (i.e. a 200 OK status) or not? You need to do some debugging.

Comment: Yes I know that it works all the way through. Already tried different approaches (edit1 above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataType - delete this one.

Add console.log and open console in Your browser

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log( data );
```

show Your console, and then You will see why. Maybe an unwanted char or php error

Second thing - there should be if stament like this (I supposed)

```
if (data == "1") // it is returning string, not integer.
```

You can also try to use switch case in success.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The first idea is awesome. It echoes somehow the whole mail sending log and the actual return value "2" appended to it. Still no idea why it does it, but know I no where to look. Thanks, completely forgot about the js console

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; because of this

Comment: OMG.....I've never seen an error so close to what I'm searching for right now. I have something very similar in functionality and it's returning the entire mail log for me as well when I'm just wanting "Success" or "Error". I'm on a solution trail! :D

Comment: @GrzegorzMiśkiewicz DUDE you're comment was my answer!! I commented out my $mail->SMTPDebug = 2 and it worked!!!!