# PHPMailer working from backend, but ajax does not return success message on frontend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I'm sending an email with PHPMailer. It's working just fine. The problem is in the ajax call. If my data returns 'null', the dialog works.

I tried if/else if/else and a switch with the success message set as the default. My console shows no feedback, and no dialog pops up. The only thing that works is the email.

The front end:

```
<body class="text-center">
<div id="incorrect_email_dialog">
    <h3>Oops! It looks like you entered an incorrect email</h3>
    <h3>Give it another try</h3>
</div>
<div id="correct_email_dialog">
    <h3>Please check the email associated with your account</h3>
    <h3>for instructions to reset your password</h3>
</div>
<div class="container login-container">
    <form id="forgot_pass_form" class="form-signin">
        <img class="login_logo" src="css/images/logos/example_logo72x72.png">
        <h1 class="font-weight-normal">Please enter email</h1>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email associated with account" required autofocus>
        <button id="login_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div class="register-container">
            <p><a class="register-p" href="login.php">Back to Login</a></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>

    var original_error_dialog = $('#incorrect_email_dialog').html();

        $('#forgot_pass_form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(email);
            console.log('Submitted form');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'includes/token_send.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    switch(data) {
                        case 'Error':
                            console.log('Error');
                            $('#incorrect_email_dialog').html('<h3>Oops. There was a problem</h3>');
                            $('#incorrect_email_dialog').dialog('open');
                            break;
                        case 'null':
                            console.log('Data was null');
                            $('#incorrect_email_dialog').html(original_error_dialog);
                            $('#incorrect_email_dialog').dialog('open');
                            break;
                        default:
                            $('#correct_email_dialog').dialog('open');
                            console.log('All good');
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```

The backend:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
include '../../config/DB.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];

    try { $db = new DB(); } catch (\Exception $e) { $e->getMessage(); }

    $result = $db->getRow('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?', [$email]);

    $input_email = $result['email'];

    if($input_email !== null) {
        $to = $input_email;
        $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'localhost';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->setFrom('noreply@example.com', '');
        $mail->addAddress($to, '');
        $mail->Subject = 'Example Password Reset Request';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = '
                <h2 style="padding:10px;background:#ec1414;font-size:16px;color:#fff;">Example Password Reset</h2>
                <br><br>
                <p>Use this link to reset your password</p>
                <br>
                <a style="text-decoration:none!important;" href="http://example.local/reset.php?token='.$token.'&email='.$input_email.'">Click here to reset</a>';
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo json_encode('Error');
        } else {
            echo json_encode('Success');
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode('null');
    }
}
```

I get the email in my inbox, but nothing after the 'Submitted Form' console.log statement.

I also tried:

```
case 'Success':
    $('#correct_email_dialog').dialog('open');
    console.log('All good');
    break;
```

in place of `default` to no avail.

Comment: I suspect you are returning more data than you think (perhaps a PHP warning notice) and so it is not valid JSON and since you have specified `dataType: 'json'` the call is failing. Try removing `dataType: 'json'` and seeing what `console.log(data)` gives you.

Comment: Try removing the `json_encode`

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` show?

Comment: console.log(data) shows a huge log of stuff. Didn't realize that was happening. I also removed dataType:'json' and it didn't change.

Comment: You will need to remove all the log stuff for your code to work. You could try using `ob_start()` at the beginning of your backend code and then call `ob_end_clean()` before you output your `JSON`.

Comment: Alright, I had it return straight up PHP and it's still returning the huge glob of code. I'm gonna do some reading on ajax params and try to fix this. Brb.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I did some digging and I found my solution [as a comment to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541124/phpmailer-return-to-ajax)

I had forgotten that I left

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

in the code! All I did was

```
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

and boom, fixed. Email sends, my jQuery dialog shows up. All is well. :)

I learned something about PHPMailer debug mode and how it interacts with Ajax today. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, friends.

Here's the console log of the mail dump going away.

[image]

And here is the ajax success calling the jQuery Dialog interaction.

[image]

Again, thanks for your help.